# Sendgrid change text and style for group unsubscribe links

Tags: email, laravel-5, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm facing one problem while sending emails with SendGrid. I'm sending normal email with assigning unsubscribe ground id. And when sending email then getting two links `Unsubscribe From This List` and `Manage Email Preferences`. Now my requirement is that I want to change these link texts from

1. Unsubscribe From This List => Unsubscribe
2. Manage Email Preferences => Update Preferences

And also links are not coming in the bottom of email. I want these after footer texts.

I'm not using marketing emails. Below is the one email screen-shot which I got:-
[image]

And below is the code for sending email. I'm using Laravel for sending emails:-

```
public function sendMail()
{
    $status = \Mail::send('emails.demo', ['name' => "testdata"], function($message)
    {
        $args = [
            'asm_group_id' => 3169

        ];
        $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', json_encode($args));
       $message->to('test@gmail.com', 'Test User')->subject('This is a demo!');
    });
}
```

Please suggest me if anyone have idea how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Check this package. https://github.com/s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver .

This is the correct format for the above package:

```
$send = \Mail::send('emails.tests.tests', compact([]),
        function (Message $message) use (
            $subject, $from_email, $from_name, $to_emails, $to_name ) {
            $message->subject($subject)
                //->attach($pathToFile)
                //->to($to_emails)
                ->to($to_emails, $to_name)
                //->cc($cc_email)
                ->from($from_email, $from_name)
                ->embedData([
                    'asm' => ['group_id' => 123],
                ],
                    'sendgrid/x-smtpapi');
        });
```

if you are not using this package then

```
        $status = Mail::send('emails.test', compact('data_var'), function($message)
    {
        $args = [
            'asm_group_id' => 123

        ];

        $message->from('testfrom@gmail.com','from name');
        $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-SMTPAPI', json_encode($args));
        $message->to('testto@gmail.com', 'Test User')
            ->subject('This is a demo!');
    });
```